# How to change subject of keyCloak "executeActions" email?

Tags: authentication, email, smtp, keycloak, freemarker

I would like to customize the subject of the emails sent using
"execute-actions-email" REST endpoint depending on the required actions,
e.g. :

- "Update your password" when the UPDATE_PASSWORD action is present
- "Verify your e-mail" when only the VERIFY_EMAIL action is present

It is possible?

Is it possible to do this from within executeActions.ftl?

I'm new to keyCloak and any help is appreciated.

I'm using this endpoint: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.2/rest-api/index.html#_executeactionsemail

I already found these lists, but nothing with a possible solution:

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-September/015456.html

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-November/016140.html

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-November/016140.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom theme for this. And under your custom theme folder create the `email` folder and under that create the `messages` folder and then you can create the file named messages_en.properties and you can have the key and values there. For the email subjects you have mentioned, you can use the below keys

```
executeActionsSubject=Action Required
eventUpdatePasswordSubject=Update password
```

You can refer to this link to develop a custom theme -- https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes